# Can i run a feature multiple times in SpecFlow?

Tags: specflow

I've been searching for a while now and i haven't found an answer to my question: can i run a feature file x times with the same inputs? The x should be a number that is in a config file.

```
Feature: SpecFlowFeature
    In order to avoid silly mistakes
    As a math idiot
    I want to be told the sum of two numbers on DEV environment <= Can I do this? Can DEV be a parameter?

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

So based on the feature above, i want to be able to read from a config file a number, that will be the number of times i want to run the same feature. In other words i want to add 50 + 70 10 times. The number of times will be read from a config file. Can i do this with Specflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I do not know how you would do this with a config file, I would advise you to create a scenario outline. For example, in your case:

```
Feature: SpecFlowFeature
In order to avoid silly mistakes
As a math idiot
I want to be told the sum of two numbers on DEV environment

@mytag
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
    And this concludes testrun number '<id>'

Examples:
|id|
|1 |
|2 |
|3 |
|...
```

Now the last step might be something void, or you could use a reporting tool to keep track of the testruns. Either way, the test is going to run as many times as the number of IDs you have in the Examples table.

You could also do:

```
Feature: SpecFlowFeature
In order to avoid silly mistakes
As a math idiot
I want to be told the sum of two numbers on DEV environment

@mytag
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered '<value1>' into the calculator
    And I have entered '<value2>' into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be '<expected value>' on the screen

Examples:
|value1|value2|expected value|
|50    |70    |120           |
|50    |70    |120           |
|50    |70    |120           |
|50    |70    |120           |
|50    |70    |120           |
|50    |70    |120           |
|...
```

Comment: How would i do this if i have a feature with multiple scenarios and i want to run the scenarios sequentially multiple times?

Comment: I'm afraid thats a limitation of specflow. You will have to make multiple Scenario Outlines, and most testrunners, by default, execute tests in alphabetical order (like nunit). So by naming the scenarios 01 Add two numbers, 02 Add five numbers etc. You can make them run sequentially. But its not going to be possible to run scenario 1 - run 1, then scenario 2 -
run 1, scenario 1 - run 2, scenario 2 - run 2. At least, not to my knowledge